# How can I modify json response and save it in state?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So for example, my json response looks like:

```
"name": "John"
"value": "5"
```

Then I pass it to my state

`commit("SET_USER", response.data.user);`

But, if name is == "John" i want the value to be 10 and pass it to mutation. Is it possible to do this?
I can access value like this `response.data.user[0].value`

```
if(response.data.user[0].name == "John") {
              response.data.user[0].value == "10"
            }
            commit("SET_USER", response.data.users); // <-- state.cards
          })
```

Comment: Is the question how to write an if statement, or something more?

Comment: I belive it's if statement, I tried comparing the user[0].value with user[0].name and then setting the value, but I dont know in which place should I put this. I kept getting error value of none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` function :

```
commit("SET_USER", response.data.user.map(item=>{
           if(item.name=='John'){
              item.value=10
           }
    return item;
}));
```

if you already know the index :

```
let users=response.data.user;
if(users[0].name == "John") {
              users[0].value = 10
            }
commit("SET_USER", users);
```